# Which metrics that can be use to know "overfitting" model"?

Tags: machine-learning, python, accuracy, overfitting

Hello everyone i'm new to data science world.
So i want to know if my model is overfitting. Usually i'm comparing training accuracy and testing accuracy. But on some reference many people using roc_auc score from training and testing and compared it to know if the model is overfit.

Which metrics evaluation better? I have imbalanced data, but already using SMOTE oversampling.

The second question i want to ask if i'm decided to use accuracy method to know if my model is overfitting, should i try using k cross validation with scoring='accuracy' to prove more?

Comment: [There are a lot of misconceptions about class imbalance](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274), and you seem to have some of them. For instance, why use SMOTE?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as you suggest, ***ROC AUC*** is a more robust metric than ***accuracy***. It is even more relevant for imbalanced datasets (very frequent in real use cases) where the model might be very good at predicting the majority class but not the minority (which is usually what you are more interested in predicting).

In this case, high **accuracy** values are **misleading** when correctly predicting true negatives, but not true positives (minority). What you need is a metric which focuses on getting good values of true positive rates (TPR), and this is something which ROC AUC considers (giving you also a value of how the model behaves considering several model thresholds):

[image] ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#roc-metrics))

Even a better metric for imbalanced datasets can be the **Precision-Recall AUC**, you can [find here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-imbalanced-classification/) a detailed comparison.

About using **cross-validation**, yes, you should always try to apply this technique, to prevent overfitting to a unique test set; this gives you **robustness** since your metric is evaluated on several k-evaluation sets ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)).

Comment: thank you for your answer, it help me to understand more. But i have one more question.. If i've already done oversampling for my training data, can i use accuracy instead of roc auc? Because from what you've state above that ''Indeed as you suggest, ROC AUC is a more robust metric than accuracy. It is even more relevant for imbalanced datasets (very frequent in real use cases) where the model might be very good at predicting the majority class but not the minority (which is usually what you are more interested in predicting)."

Comment: I would first try to train the model using ROC AUC and not using oversampling; actually, I would rather use undersampling instead of oversampling in case the first approach is not good enough (you can try both ways)